# Why don't the image and h3 tag appear in order on different sized screens?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, dom

I have this image and h3 tag which appears out of order on different screens, I want both to be in the center, no disorder.

I tried:

```
<body style="background-color:tomato; color:white; font-family:Consolas; font-weight:600">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <img style="width: 26%; position: absolute; margin-left: 36%; margin-top: -14%;"  class="img-responsive" src="~/Content/images/404.png" />
                    <h3 style="margin-left: 24%; margin-top: 39%;;">Oops, this page does not exists. Go back to @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 "></div>
</body>
```

Comment: It's unclear how the final result should look like. Do you want the image to be next to the text, or below it? Why do you need to many styles applied directly to the element, this shouldn't be necessary when using bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

I just changed your code, refer below HTML

```
<body style="background-color:tomato; color:white; font-family:Consolas; font-weight:600">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                  <img style="width: 26%; margin: 14% auto 0 auto; display: block;"  class="img-responsive" 
                      src="https://www.seoclerk.com/pics/want54841-1To5V31505980185.png" />
                  <h3 style="text-align: center;">Oops, this page does not exists. Go back to @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</h3>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 "></div>
```

changed img tag styles. to take the img tag to the center of a div set **left and right margins to auto** and make the img tag **display to block**. also when using margin left and right auto to center an an element you will have to set width to the element.

in h3 tag all you need is add **text-align: center**

hope this fix your problem.